# AJAX update list of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Can someone help me and say whats wrong I did?

In my django project I have `product_detail` page which has comment part. I am tring to update comments list after successfully adding new comment with AJAX. Unfortunatly it updates all page. I am little bit comfused and need advice. I need to update only list of comments not all page.

**product_detail.html:**

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-block">
      <table id="comment-table">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Author</th>
               <th>Date</th>
               <th>Comment Text</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            {% include 'project/comment_list.html' %}
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>

   <div class="card-footer">
   <form method="post" class="comment-form" id="comment-form" action="{% url 'project:comment_add' project_code=project.code product_code=product.code %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
         {% for field in form %}
         <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
            {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                 <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
         </div>
         {% endfor %}
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

**views.py:**

```
def comment_add(request, project_code, product_code):
    data = dict()
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_code, status='open')
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_code)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            product.comments.add(comment)
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            data['html_comment'] = render_to_string('project/comment_list.html', {'product': product})
            form = CommentForm()
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context = {'project': project, 'product': product, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'project/product_detail.html', context)
```

**js:**

```
$(function () {
    var saveForm = function () {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    $("#comment-table tbody").html(data.html_comment);
                }
                else {
                    $("#comment-form").html(data.html_comment_form);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    };

    $("#comment-form").on("submit", ".comment-form", saveForm);
});
```

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago. Try to add onclick="return false;" to the html button. You can also try to make the button type="button" and change your event listener on the #comment-form.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/...

Comment: Thanks for advice. I tried to do what you said but it seems to me that  code still update page and not the list cause after success adding it goes to the top of the page and also url adress changes to `/comment_add/` when it must be still in `/product_detail/`. What can you advice to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is type="submit" native refresh new page. You have to stop form submitting. Try something like this:

```
$("#comment-form").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();


     // here your ajax code
});
```

Comment: Well I tried next code but it seems like it update page and not the list cause after success adding it goes to the top of the page and also url adress changes to `/comment_add/` when it must be still in `/product_detail/`. What can you advice to me?

Comment: Do a jsfiddle with dummy data and i can help you